# Asp.net unhandled exception in timer callback crashes w3wp and error not logged

Tags: asp.net, exception, iis, crash, event-viewer

I am experiencing some randomly happening unhandled exception causing w3wp to crash. I want to trace the cause of that exception. I already have a global Application_Error handler override in my MvcApplication class, so the crash must be caused by some out-of-http-context exception. In order to replicate the problem I genereate one myself in a timer callback, and try to trace it. Simplified code like

```
public static class MonitorTimers
{
    public static Timer _taskMonitorTimer = new Timer(state: null, dueTime: 1000, period: 1000, callback: (state) =>
    {
        throw new Exception("Ouch! Me dead.");
    });     
}
```

In my local development environment (iisexpress launched by VS2017) and test environment (IIS 8.5), when the app starts and then crashes, the following can be seen in event viewer:

[image]

The most useful Event 1325 and 1026 sourced from `ASP.NET` and `.NET Runtime` shows the stack trace - just the thing I need.

My problem is, in my production machine (also IIS 8.5) I can't find the useful event 1325. Only a crash report, bearing no more information than I know. So I don't know what caused the error. I could surround my timer callback with try...catch block but the error could well be caused by something else (unmanaged libraries, error in static class initialization) then I still can't trace.

So suggestions on why event 1325 is missing or some tools that can show the log and analyse the stack trace is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: `0xc0000005` is a native error code (access violation), so the worker process was crashed by a native memory issue, not an unhandled exception as you guessed. That's why your attempt to find the event log entry failed, and why you should use tools such as Debug Diag, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/919792/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-a-process-that-h If you never use such tools in the past, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com for help.

Comment: @LexLi You're exactly right. The scenario I constructed is different from the production problem. I think there's some unmanaged code from GhostScript that caused the error because the error only surfaced after adding that library. I will try to learn Debug Daig. Meanwhile do you have any other suggestion on stack tracing the faulty line? I do want to narrow it down and try...catch it within the .NET framework if possible.

Comment: No. It is impossible to handle native crash on .NET side.

Comment: Thank you Lex. What I end up doing is wrapping the Ghostscript function call in a separate console executable and start that process from IIS, so that it can crash on its own. Debugging native code in a 3rd library is a bit beyond me at the moment I'm afraid.

Comment: Then you can post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score -1):

So, in your case you generate Exception diring Loading of application domain. 
When CLR load application domain it firstly init static fields. So, if your code has problem with static fields, then exception will throw until it specifies `Application_Error`  handler.

**One more point**, Is your application take a lot of memory? There are 2 cases when application can not write logs and execute code in `catch` block: StackOverflowException and OutOfMemoryException. Can you check is it has some memory leaks or infinite recursion?

**One more point**: set in visual studion setting to break when any exception throwed.

**One more point**: It is better to move your initialization logic from static constructors to ApplicationStart or something like this. You can do it temporary, for catch the bag and then move it to previous state.